# How to solve : Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using `redux-thunk/ReactJs` for async actions and i am getting error like this `Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

But i have installed `redux-thunk` and have configured it in `index.js` file

Here is my `index.js` file :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import myReducer from './reducers/index';
const store = createStore(
    myReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    );
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

and this is my 'action.js' file :

```
import * as types from './../constants/ActionTypes';
import callApi from '../utils/callApi';

export const actFetchProductsRequest = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        return callApi('products', 'GET', null).then(res => {
            dispatch(actFetchProducts(res.data))
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}

export const actFetchProducts = (products) => {
    return {
        type: types.LIST_ALL,
        products
    }
}
```

What is the problem here , thanks ?

Comment: Hi have a look here: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/issues/146 - I recently solved the same issue with this.

Comment: It doesn't work :( . But thank for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export const actFetchProducts = (products) => {
    return ({
        type: types.LIST_ALL,
        products
    })
}
```

You need to put the return object in the parentheses. If you don't, then you'll definitely get this error.

[image]

Hopefully, that helps!